# How to make my self defined exception handler catches the error sooner than the built-in ValueError exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have already checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020122/how-to-raise-my-exceptions-instead-of-built-in-exceptions) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56900247/use-of-exception-init-self-for-user-defined-exceptions) but their answers didn't work with my question.
I have a function that checks if the date string taken from the user is valid and if not then the self created exception catches it:

```
import time

class MyException(Exception):
   
    def __init__(self, expression):
        self.expression = expression


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.expression} is not in the range 1-12.'


def my_fun(date_string):

    try:
        d = time.strptime(date_string, "%d/%m/%Y")
        if not (1 <= int(d[1]) <= 12):
            raise MyException(d[1]) from None

    except MyException as e:
        print(e)
```

As I am using 'time.strptime' before the if statement, when the invalid date like 02/14/2020 is passed to the function, the python itself catches `ValueError` exception with the message:

```
"time data '02/14/2020' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'"
```

and doesn't let MyException to catch the exception although I am using `from None` according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020122/how-to-raise-my-exceptions-instead-of-built-in-exceptions).
How do I fix it?

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks. I removed pass. The reason is I try to display a message that that tells the user which part of the date is wrong e.g. if the month is entered as 14 then it is out of range 1-12.

Comment: You have a chicken-and-egg problem. Essentially your code is attempting to use the results of a `strptime()` call that failed, so there's no `d` to reference — so it's impossible.

Comment: @martineau And I don't think there's any way to take the month or day from the date string, other than `time.strptime(date_string, "%d/%m/%Y")`, right?

Comment: You could parse the string manually using the `re` regular expression (RegEx)  module, or some other way. There are third-party modules available that might be helpful. A popular one is named [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/).

Comment: @martineau Thanks.